# Who's the next target?

Tags: cipher

Kenny's a serial killer and he likes to play games. To make his killing spree more interesting, he leaves clues for the detectives on his next victim. One day, the police station received a message as below:

```
  Kenny: ";9;9;jlk "

  Kenny: "l l"
```

The police were able to immediately trace where the message was coming from and went to the source destination. Upon arrival, they saw nothing special but a grand piano with Beethoven's music sheets.

Who's the next target?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's Elise. With cup-size "double d" :D

/edit: Second thought: it could be Elise's Dad :|

Explanation:
one of the most famous play from beethoven is "For Elise". It starts with the following:

[image]

First message from Kenny are the starting notes. Regarding the second message and combining the notes, [L L] results in "DAD".

Comment: That was quick. :D

Comment: Just for curiosity: is it elise herself or her dad? just wondering about that second "l l".

Comment: Kenny was supposed to be killing his own dad, but I guess I didn't manage the variable very well. :/ The purpose of the first clue is to "map" the keys

Comment: am I the only one who doesn't get where did Elise, double D and her dad came from?

Comment: @novarg: I added an explanation.

Comment: @buffo ok, thanks. If only I would have some musical background I would probably understand it more :)

Comment: seriously guys you have all that spare time in the world to imagine this ..

Comment: So the second message corresponds to the musical notes "D," "A," and "D"? How do the messages correspond to the music?

Comment: @KSmarts - Step 1: this music is the only piano composition by Beethoven that is clearly associated with a person's name.  Step 2: the first message is a substitution cipher for the 1st eight notes of the music.  I imagine that only a small fraction of good pianists could have recognized this as fast as buffo.

Comment: And I just realized the 9th character in the cipher is a space which corresponds to A.

Comment: Should be 0, not 9, I think.